# Filtering throung a listed text

Tags: bash, sed, awk, scripting, grep

I have a list of text that looks like this:

```
function.o U out
function.o T fail
function.o U main
myPart.o T out
myPart.o U fail
```

and so on...

I want the final list to look like this:

```
The .o file with U beside it : The .o file with T beside it /the third column they have both/
```

So the example up there would look like this filtered:

```
function.o : myPart.o /out/
myPart.o : function.o /fail/
```

So I list only the lines that have the same symbol in the third column (like *out*, *fail* and so on). Until now I came up with this:

```
awk '$3 in t{ln[$3]=t[$3]" -> "$1;next}{t[$3]=$1}END{for(s in ln) print ln[s],"("s")"}' "$file"
```

But that prints everything without accounting for the U/T symbol. Any ideas please?

Comment: What happens if there is an entry like `function.o U fail`?

Comment: There can't be both `function.o U fail` and `function.o T fail`. It's an nm output.

Comment: In your output shouldnt it be `myPart.o : function.o /out/` instead of `/fail/`?

Comment: Yeah, I think the sample output is reversed on the third field isn't it?

Comment: no, because myPart.o is dependent on function.o towards `out`. the T means its defined in the function while U means it depends on the other function. thus `dependent(U) : defined(T) /on what/`

Comment: sorry, I specified the U and T symbolism wrong. now it should all make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '
$3 in t{line[$3]=($2=="U")?$1" : "t[$3]:t[$3]" : "$1;next}{t[$3]=$1}
END{for(k in line) print line[k],"/"k"/"}
' file
myPart.o : function.o /fail/
function.o : myPart.o /out/
```

Comment: unbelievable! thanks for your amazing work. now I can finally get back to making it work.

Comment: one more thing, if I want it not only for T on the right, but for more specified letters (like T and A and F...), how do I edit that?

Comment: This solution only checks for second column to be U. If it is it puts it first. Rest everything will get pushed to the right. So in short it will work for other letters without any change.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
{
    file[$3,$2] = $1
    thirds[$3]++
}

END {
    for (third in thirds) {
        if (file[third,"T"]) {
            print file[third,"T"], ":", file[third,"U"], "/" third "/"
        }
    }
}
```